# Jenkins: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I have initially setup sonar as localhost:9000, but now i changed to some IP like 172.1.1.1:9000 but still jenkins pointing to old configuration i started multiple time cleared cache in .sonar but i keep on getting below error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.1.1168:sonar (default-cli) on project infrastructure-test: 
Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000: Connection refused:
```

Comment: No errors in the SonarQube logs?

Comment: Are you sure you updated Jenkins' global configuration to point to the new address?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam yes i verified it multiple times. but now i figured it out  i tried once with -Dsonar.host.url=http://172.16.1.1:9000 and on second try i removed it and now its working fine. Some cache issue at jenkins